# Local Apache Server - Refusing to connect after trying to install PHP5.6 through bash script

Tags: php, apache, localhost

My local apache server was working fine on PHP 7.1, however I was trying to install PHP 5.6 due to a current projecting using deprecated functions.

I ran the following command to try install PHP 5.6

> curl -s https://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 5.6

After extracting the PHP files, the following ran:

```
Executing post-install script /tmp/5.6-10.10-frontenddev-post-install
Create symlink /usr/local/php5/entropy-php.conf 
/etc/apache2/other/+php-osx.conf
Restarting Apache
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/usr/docs/dummy-host.example.com] does 
not exist
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/usr/docs/dummy-host2.example.com] 
does not exist
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully 
qualified domain name, using 192.168.1.126. Set the 'ServerName' 
directive globally to suppress this message
Syntax OK
Finished.
```

Not really to sure whats going on, but my local vhosts are all refusing to connect after running the command.

**Apache Error Log**

```
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/usr/docs/dummy-host.example.com] does 
not exist
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/usr/docs/dummy-host2.example.com] does 
not exist
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully 
qualified 
domain name, using 192.168.1.126. Set the 'ServerName' directive 
globally 
to suppress this message
[Fri Feb 22 11:49:47.580441 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 12019] 
AH00163: Apache/2.4.33 (Unix) PHP/7.1.16 configured -- resuming normal 
operations
[Fri Feb 22 11:49:47.580524 2019] [core:notice] [pid 12019] AH00094: 
Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Fri Feb 22 12:00:14.719520 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 12019] 
AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
```

Can anyone please help me get my apache local server up and running again. I ideally need it so I can switch between PHP5.6 + PHP7.

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

> /etc/apache2.other/+php-osx.conf

```
#
# Additional PHP Apache directives,
# part of the entropy.ch PHP package for Mac OS X
#
# For more information, go to http://www.entropy.ch/software/macosx/php/
#

LoadModule php5_module        /usr/local/php5/libphp5.so

<IfModule mod_php5.c>

    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
    AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps

    <IfModule mod_dir.c>
        DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
    </IfModule>

</IfModule>
```

Commenting out the line to loadmodule brings my apache back :) Guess it was because it was loading PHP7 from httpd.conf. Although commenting out PHP 7 in httpd.conf and enabling PHP 5 still runs PHP7?

Comment: What's in /etc/apache2/other/+php-osx.conf?

Comment: I've updated my question. I was to give you a big thank you for pointing me to this file. Manage to atleast get apache running again, just got a couple of warnings.

AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 192.168.1.126. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message

Although in httpd.conf - ServerName is set to 127.0.0.1 ??

Comment: Try `localhost` instead of 127.0.0.1

Comment: Still get the same warning

Comment: Do you know how I can revert apache back to default? May just do this as I only have one site setup currently, so may be easiler?

Comment: Hmm, that's weird. Maybe php5 modified some other config files without saying anything about it? I'm not sure. I think if you backup anything you want to save then just delete all of the config files and reinstall apache, it should replace the missing files with the default ones.

Comment: Well Im glad it seems to be running atleast, just get errors trying to stop apache lol - AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 192.168.1.126. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
httpd (no pid file) not running

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188896/discussion-between-layne-bernardo-and-heady12).